# How do I unit test a custom ActionFilter in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, tdd, actionfilterattribute

So I'm creating a custom ActionFilter that's based mostly on this project http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/aspnet_mvc_restapi.aspx.

I want a custom action filter that uses the http accept headers to return either JSON or Xml. A typical controller action will look like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[AcceptTypesAttribute(HttpContentTypes.Json, HttpContentTypes.Xml)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var articles = Service.GetRecentArticles();

    return View(articles);
}
```

The custom filter overrides the OnActionExecuted and will serialize the object (in this example articles) as either JSON or Xml.

**My question is: how do I test this?**

1. What tests do I write? I'm a TDD novice and am not 100% sure what I should be testing and what not to test. I came up with `AcceptsTypeFilterJson_RequestHeaderAcceptsJson_ReturnsJson()`, `AcceptsTypeFilterXml_RequestHeaderAcceptsXml_ReturnsXml()` and `AcceptsTypeFilter_AcceptsHeaderMismatch_ReturnsError406()`.
2. How do I test an ActionFilter in MVC that is testing the Http Accept Headers?

Thanks.

Comment: Future readers may want to look at this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629391/how-to-mock-actionexecutingcontext-with-moq/39491397#39491397

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You just need to test the filter itself. Just create an instance and call the `OnActionExecuted()` method with test data then check the result. It helps to pull the code apart as much as possible. Most of the heavy lifting is done inside the `CsvResult` class which can be tested individually. You don't need to test the filter on an actual controller. Making that work is the MVC framework's responsibility.

```
public void AcceptsTypeFilterJson_RequestHeaderAcceptsJson_ReturnsJson()
{
    var context = new ActionExecutedContext();
    context.HttpContext = // mock an http context and set the accept-type. I don't know how to do this, but there are many questions about it.
    context.Result = new ViewResult(...); // What your controller would return
    var filter = new AcceptTypesAttribute(HttpContentTypes.Json);

    filter.OnActionExecuted(context);

    Assert.True(context.Result is JsonResult);
}
```

Comment: I don't know when it changed, but in .Net Core 3.1 `ActionExecutedContext` does not have a no-arg constructor, making setup more difficult.

Answer (score 17):

I just stumbled upon [this blog post](https://www.donnfelker.com/mvc-unit-testing-action-filters/) which seems the right way to me. He uses [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4).

What this chap is doing is mocking the `HTTPContext`, but also we need to set up a ContentType in the request:

```cs
// Mock out the context to run the action filter.
var request = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
request.SetupGet(r => r.ContentType).Returns("application/json");
    
var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
httpContext.SetupGet(c => c.Request).Returns(request.Object);
 
var routeData = new RouteData(); //
routeData.Values.Add("employeeId", "123");
 
var actionExecutedContext = new Mock<ActionExecutedContext>();
actionExecutedContext.SetupGet(r => r.RouteData).Returns(routeData);
actionExecutedContext.SetupGet(c => c.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext.Object);
 
var filter = new EmployeeGroupRestrictedActionFilterAttribute();
 
filter.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext.Object);
```

Note - I have not tested this myself.