# Unit Test and attribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, attributes, asp.net-web-api2

I have the following attribute:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ActionArguments["model"] == null)
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, new HttpError("Model is null") { { "CustomErrorCode", "480" } });

        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        //base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
}
```

and the WebAPI method:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateModel]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SignUpAsync(ApiModels.RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerApiModel model)
        {
....
        }
```

It work as expected, but when I want to write Unit Test:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public async Task SignUp_InvalidModelState()
    {
        ApiModels.RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerApiModel model1 = new ApiModels.RegisterAsSmartphonePhotographerApiModel()
        {
            Username = "abc"
        };
        HttpResponseMessage result1 = await controller.SignUpAsync(model1);
        Assert.IsFalse(result1.IsSuccessStatusCode);
        Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result1, typeof(BadRequestResult));
    }
```

I get an exception because ValidateModelAttribute is not called. How can I "include" ValidateModel validation to unit test?

Comment: I'd test the `ValidateModelAttribute` separately as described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8508700/502395) answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should test ValidateModelAttribute by itself. How it works when you decorate/annotate your method in the controller should be the frameworks responsibility.