# Custom Model binding mixing Route and Body data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have a model with 3 properties that I want to bind and validate using ASP.NET Core. From this 3 properties, 2 should be bind from the POSTed JSON body, and the third should be bind from a route parameters:

```
public class CustomModel
{
    public string Id_Model { get; set; } //Bind it from RouteData
    public string Value { get; set; } //Bind it from Body
    public string Type { get; set; } //Bind it from Body
}

[Route("[controller]")]
public CustomController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("{Id_Model}")]
    public IActionResult Post(CustomModel model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

The thing is also that I don't want to add any attributes on the model itself (it will be declared in another assembly, and I don't want dependencies from `Microsoft.AspNetCore` in this assembly).

I've tried to create a CustomModelBinder, but I'm stuck with only the Route Data available from `bindingContext.ValueProvider`, and I don't know how to fetch Body/Json Data.

I've tried to use `FormValueProviderFactory`, and instanciate one with `new ValueProviderFactoryContext(bindingContext.ActionContext)` but the resulting provider is always `null`.

Any idea how this kind of mixed binding can be done ?

Comment: If you find that you need to use the binding attributes, you can always derive a class and/or use the adapter pattern.

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried to create a CustomModelBinder, but I'm stuck with only the Route Data available from bindingContext.ValueProvider, and I don't know how to fetch Body/Json Data.

You can read request body in custom model binder :

```
public class testDtoEntityBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
            }

            bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
            var body = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
            body.Position = 0;


            string raw = new System.IO.StreamReader(body).ReadToEnd();

            //now read content from request content and fill your model 
            var result = new testDto
            {
                A = "",
                B = 1,
            };


            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

Use like below on your model:

```
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(testDtoEntityBinder))]
```

You can also get route data from `bindingContext.HttpContext.Request`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you meant this:

```
[HttpPost("{Id_Model}")]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody] CustomModel model, string Id_Model)
{
    model.Id_Model = Id_Model;

    // rest of the code as you wish

    return Ok(model);
}
```

So, you can catch it as you **POST** the following to this endpoint:`http://localhost:63676/Custom/100`

[image]

Hope this helped.

Comment: That's almost it, but I want to use the Model Validation from `IValidatableObject`, included with the `[ApiControllerAttribute]`, and the validation for the `CustomModel` require the `Id_Model` to be set. That's why I would like to bind it before the execution of the Action.

Comment: You'll find this thread useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50481226/in-web-api-core-how-to-do-model-validation-in-every-method

Comment: It's useful, but still, the Model Validation happens before executing the action itself (with or without the the `[ApiControllerAttribute]`, so ModelState will be `false` even if I manually set the the `Id_Model`.