# Test custom ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing

I have created a custom ActionFilterAttribute named ThrottleFilter. It has the scope of preventing the user of making too many requests at the same time ( No more than 4 calls can be run for a specific action in a span of 10 seconds). I use it to decorate some specific actions in the controller.

It works fine, but my dilemma is : how could I write a test for it? 
(I have not added code as it's not a a few lines and I guess the solution is more general - but I can provide it if necessary);

Comment: By test are you referring to unit test or integration test?

Comment: @Nkosi Unit test

Comment: Can you confirm platform version? .net Core?

Comment: NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2  ( using Moq for testing )

Comment: asp.net MVC 5 or Web API?

Comment: Using Web Api .

Comment: Alright. will need to see some code for the attribute to better advise you

Comment: There is an answer here for Asp.Net Core which might be similar but things have changed between the version you are using and now https://stackoverflow.com/a/46163116/5233410

Comment: @Nkosi With the use of that and other responses I have been able to test it.
Thank you.