# c# Unit test mock class attribute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-5

In my MVC project I had to setup a controller class attribute:

```
public class ResponsableAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        var controller = (BaseController)filterContext.Controller;
        if (!controller.EstResponsable)
        {
            filterContext.Result = controller.RedirectionForcee(Alertage.Information, ConstantesUi.Misc.MessageResponsable);
        }
    }
}
```

Bear with me, the code's in french:

```
[Responsable]
public class ParamLivraisonController : BaseController
```

So every action has to pass through the attribute before being executed, which is the intended behavior.
But I do not know how to unit test this attribute, set the return value as false so that the `controller.RedirectionForcee` (which returns a `RedirectToRouteResult`) actually does its job.

If I call any controller method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ParamLivraisonController_GererLivraison_Get()
{
    ControleurAsynchrone.ObtenirLivraisons().Returns(ObtenirListeLivraison());
    var retour = _ctrl.GererLivraisons();
    Assert.IsNotNull(retour);
}
```

The attribute is not hit or tested. How can test it? I am using nSubstitute with mvcFakes and I do not know how to substitute `ActionExecutingContext`.

Comment: The subject of the isolated *Unit Test* should be the attribute. Create a context you control and pass that to the `OnActionExecuting` and assert the desired behavior. Otherwise create an in memory Integration Test that will invoke the action end to end at run-time, which would include also the attribute.

Comment: Interesting! Would you mind throwing an example please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mock ActionExecutingContext with Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629391/how-to-mock-actionexecutingcontext-with-moq)

Comment: @KennethK. Did not even know it was possible. :|

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Kenneth K., I found the answer. @Nkosi was right as well to mention that the test should be on the attribute itself.

Here it is:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ValiderAttribut_EstResponsable()
    {
        var attribut = new ResponsableAttribute(); // Instantiation of the attribute
        var controller = ObtenirController(); // Gets the controller via MvcFakes
        SecuriteHelper.VerifierResponsable().Returns(true); // Sets the desired return value
        var test = Substitute.For<ActionExecutingContext>(); // Substitute for ActionExecutingContext
        test.Controller = controller; // Sets the controller to the context

        attribut.OnActionExecuting(test); // Call the overrided method
        Assert.IsNull(test.Result); // Check if the redirection occured
    }
```

Now, to validate if the test was right, I also had to test the opposite result:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ValiderAttribut_EstNonResponsable()
    {
        var attribut = new ResponsableAttribute();
        var controller = ObtenirController();
        SecuriteHelper.VerifierResponsable().Returns(false);
        var test = Substitute.For<ActionExecutingContext>();
        test.Controller = controller;

        attribut.OnActionExecuting(test);
        Assert.IsNotNull(test.Result);
        Assert.AreEqual(typeof(RedirectResult), test.Result.GetType());
    }
```

And it worked. Thanks!

Comment: And just to complete the picture, I would probably add tests using reflection to ensure that the attribute is on the `ParamLivraisonController` class; so that if someone who doesn't understand why it's there removes it, a test will fail, and the name of the test will explain why that attribute needs to be there.