# How to mock ActionExecutingContext with moq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am trying to mock `ActionExecutingContext` for `OnActionExecutionAsync`.

I need to write unit test case for below code.

```
public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(
           ActionExecutingContext context,
           ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    var controllerInfo = actionExecutingcontext.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;

    MyCustomAttribute[] myCustomAttribute = (MyCustomAttribute[])controllerInfo.MethodInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyCustomAttribute), inherit: true);
}
```

I found this [How to mock ActionExecutingContext with Moq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629391/how-to-mock-actionexecutingcontext-with-moq) useful but it doesn't explain how to mock `methodInfo` and `GetCustomAttributes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran into a similar issue trying to mock `ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors`. Since you are using MethodInfo you'll need to solve it a little differently than I did. This is working for me without Moq.  It boils down to getting an instance of MethodInfo whether it's the real method, a fake class / method with the same attribute you want to test, or a mocked MethodInfo.

```
        private static ActionExecutingContext CreateActionExecutingContextTest()
        {
            Type t = typeof(TestClass);

            var activator = new ViewDataDictionaryControllerPropertyActivator(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider());
            var actionContext = new ActionContext(
                new DefaultHttpContext(),
                new RouteData(),
                new ControllerActionDescriptor()
                {
                    // Either Mock MethodInfo, feed in a fake class that has the attribute you want to test, or just feed in
                    MethodInfo = t.GetMethod(nameof(TestClass.TestMethod))
                });
            var controllerContext = new ControllerContext(actionContext);
            var controller = new TestController()
            {
                ControllerContext = controllerContext
            };

            activator.Activate(controllerContext, controller);

            return new ActionExecutingContext(
                actionContext,
                new List<IFilterMetadata>(),
                new Dictionary<string, object>(),
                controller);
        }

        public class TestClass
        {
            [MyCustomAttribute]
            public void TestMethod()
            {
            }
        }
```